# How to find out what change broke the build from multiple commits?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

Given that we cannot build on every commit, we end up building from multiple commits.  Typically this is about 30 commits to a build.

Eventually, we break the build. How does one go about identifying and fixing code changes that introduce regressions? Are there any practices to tracking down the bad commit?

Comment: You may want to think about how often does this happen, how much time does it cost you when it does (including tracking down the breaker), and how much time or whatever it is you think you're saving by not building more frequently. "Can't build on every commit" does not necessarily mean "must have 30 commits before we can build".

Comment: Good point, but we also have some infrastructure limitations.

Comment: Who says you can't build every commit? At my work every commit must pass a build and all unit test otherwise it is rejected. SOP is to run all tests and builds locally before you even try a commit.

Comment: Sometimes is the way to go. Look at builds from Open Source world, there are plenty of builds from multiple commits. It happens.

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: IMHO this question would be quite on-topic on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generically, the best you can do is a simple [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). You start by building the commit half way between the last known good build and your current broken build, then repeat until you find the failing commit. With 30 commits, you're going to have to do ceil(log_2(30)) = 5 builds to find the failing commit. `git bisect` can help you with the tooling here, but it's not going to solve the problem for you. The naive implementation here assumes there's only one state transition in the set of commits being investigated; things get even more complicated if the set of changes goes good-bad-good-bad or if you have multiple breaking changes in there, but a first implementation can ignore those cases and just throw them out to a human - hopefully, you're not breaking the build *that* often. If you can run parallel builds, you can do N-way splitting instead of just binary.

You *may* be able to come up with some heuristics to help here; if your compiler is reporting an error on line X of file Y and `git blame` indicates that line was changed in the set of commits under investigation, then it might be worth trying just that build and the immediately previous one (which you can do in parallel). You'd have to get your own stats on whether that optimisation is worth it for how you break the build.

Comment: +1 Apparently, Google is doing something different. They also mentioned your  great suggestion (git bisect). https://research.google.com/pubs/pub45794.html

Comment: Another related solution is used by Zuul CI. They called it Gatting: https://docs.openstack.org/infra/zuul/user/gating.html, but for sure requires a lot of computing resource.